# Removing eval from PHP function

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know if there is a way to remove `eval()` from my code.

In this function I load by POST some vars to update or insert a new user on my DB based on what the admin has inserted on the form.

```
public function alterUser()
{
    
    $name = $_POST['name']; //required field 
    $contact = $_POST['contact']; //required field 
    $password = $_POST['password']; //required field 
    
    $string = "DB::table('users')";
    
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $string = $string."-> where ('id', \$_POST['id']) ->update([";
    }else{
        $string = $string."-> insert([";
    }
    
    $string = $string."'name' => \$_POST['name'],";
            
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) 
        $string = $string."'email' => \$_POST['email'],";
    
    $string = $string."'password' => Hash::make(\$password),'contacto' => \$contact,";
    
    if (isset($_POST['nif'])) 
        $string = "$string.'nif' => \$nif,";
    
    $string = $string."]);";

    eval($string);
    return redirect('/user');
}
```

As this opens some security vulnerabilities there are any other alternatives to get this working?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Thanks! @RiggsFolly.

Comment: And whenever you get the urge to use `eval()` slap yourself very hard and try and think of another way. Specifically here there is **absolutely no need for it**

Comment: Why is eval so bad to use? I dind't know it where that bad .

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use `eval()` here. You can easy assign the values of each of those strings to a variable to build up a query builder object. Heck, build up an array of the values then decide what to do with it

Comment: I should also mention that Stackoverflow isn't really the site to be posting questions asking for code cleanup and similar. Please use CodeReview for that: https://codereview.stackexchange.com. The reason you're getting answers here is that your question contains an unsafe practice of using `eval()` where not necessary, but generally, these kinds of questions are downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you could simplify your code a lot, and remove the need for `eval()` which you shouldn't use unless it is a last resort.

There is no need for all the IF blocks had in your code, because if the value isn't set, it also won't be added to the `$values` array.

Just assign your `$_POST` variable to a `$values` variable, Laravel does most of the heavy lifting for you.

```
public function alterUser()
{

    $values = $_POST;

    //remove _token variable created by Laravel in all POST requests
    unset($values['_token']); 

    //perform any actions needed on values before being send to database
    $values['password'] = Hash::make($values['password']);

    if(!empty($values['id'])) {
        DB::table('users')->insert($values);
    } else {
        DB::table('users')->where('id', $values['id'])->update($values);
    }
    
    return redirect('/user');
}
```

I see in your code that you rename the `contact` variable to `contacto`. I recommend changing your form to match this variable name, but if that isn't possible, you can still rename it after setting `$values = $_POST` like this:

```
$values['contacto'] = $values['contact'];
unset($values['contact']);
```

Also, if your form sends any variables that you do NOT want to send to the database, such as a "password verify" field or something like that, then you can unset them after setting `$values = $_POST` like this:

```
unset($values['VALUE_TO_REMOVE']);
```

Comment: I tried you code but it returns me the error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'field list'

Comment: Does your `$_POST` contain a key called `_token`? If so, read the part of my answer about removing variables you don't want sent to the database.

Comment: All `POST` requests in Laravel _should_ contain an `_token` field. It's a CSRF token that, unless explicitly configured, is required and included.

Comment: @TimLewis That's fine, I'm suggesting OP remove it from the `$values` array, not directly from the `$_POST`. Added it to my answer since it's expected of Laravel to send this value.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yup! I'm just clarifying what the `_token` field is, cause the OP may or may not be aware of it's existence :)

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks! I didn't know either :) I'm not very familiar with Laravel at all.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Haha no worries! Unfortunately, this question doesn't do a great job showcasing Laravel's approach to anything (i.e. in Laravel, I've never used `$_POST`, since `$request` is available with all requests), etc etc. This code can be improved _a lot_ more, but see my comment on the original question. SO generally isn't the place for that kind of answer.

Comment: Already removed the fields i didn't want in my DB but even after that ei gives me the error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'users.PRIMARY' , error that my first code weren't retuning.

Comment: @davidsi02 That has to do with some key constraint you have set in your mysql, not with the code here. You have a column that is limited to no duplicates, and are trying to insert a duplicate key

Comment: I made it work, is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: @davidsi02 Simplify it? That's what I've already done

Comment: How, I'm sorry but my edit didn't have been submited, I neded to change somethings in you code to make it work, I wanna now if there is anyway to simplify this: `public function alterUser()
  {
    $values = $_POST;
    if($values['id'] == 0) unset($values['id']);
    unset($values['_token']);
    unset($values['uid']);

    $values['password'] = Hash::make($values['password']);

    if(!isset($values['id'])) {
      DB::table('users')->insert($values);
    } else {
      DB::table('users')->where('id', $values['id'])->update($values);
    }
    return redirect('/user');
  }`

Comment: @davidsi02 You'll need to update your question with that code, the formatting in comments makes it really hard to vet code.

Comment: Updated now. Sorry, I'm new in stack overflow.

Comment: @davidsi02 Your code is already pretty simple. I don't think there is really anything you can do to simplify it further.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, there is absolutely no reason to use eval here. What you need to do is build up an array of values that you want to pass in, then decide if it needs to be a new user or an update.

```
public function alterUser()
{

    $name = $_POST['name']; //required field
    $contact = $_POST['contact']; //required field
    $password = $_POST['password']; //required field

    $values = [
        'name' => $name,
        'password' => Hash::make($password),
        'contacto' => $contact
    ];

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $values['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['nif'])) {
        $values['nif'] = $_POST['nif'];
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['id'])) {
        DB::table('users')->insert($values);
    } else {
        DB::table('users')->where('id', $_POST['id'])->update($values);
    }
    
    return redirect('/user');
}
```

Comment: Answered my own question by looking at the docs. With the way `insert($values)` works, why not just get rid of everything before the IF block containing the database calls, and make `$values = $_POST`? Then of course after that you could do like `$values['password'] = Hash::make($values['password']);` for anything that needs to be directly changed? That would make the code more clean IMO

Comment: I understand your point, but my eval parameters are created into the function, how can that be exploited or unsafe?

Comment: @davidsi02 Because you are using user input to create the string you are passing to `eval()`. Anyone can type anything into that input box, it's a similar problem to SQL Injection.

Comment: Yes, but eval runs a string with other code than just the values in the input, so, how can they run any code on my server without getting errors?

I'm not doubting on you, I just want to understand better this.

Comment: @davidsi02 It may not have an incredibly obvious way to inject malicious code, but you also don't know for sure that they can't. It's just safer to not use it when you don't need to.

Comment: eval also makes the code extremely messy and convoluted. Don't need it unless it's absolutely necessary. And even then, see if there's another wya to do it.

Comment: And, in regards to the word "cleaner" in your title, `eval($string)` as you have it now is really unclear. What is `$string`? Since you're modifying it a bunch of times before, with a bunch of conditionals, it's really hard to tell exactly what code you're executing.

Comment: Even since this code is only used on admin areas?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton You can do that, but occasionally $_POST contains things you may want to verify but not pass in. Like a verify password field. In the end, it comes down to what the intention is and preference.

Comment: @aynber I like how you re-factored the code. I have a few small recommendations based on your answer, should I create a new answer?

Comment: @aynber Yes, please :)

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir Probably? I think so.

Answer (score 0):

A very strong answer by @aynber
just to add to his answer, I would break down the logic into smaller parts to make it easier to read.

```
public function alterUser()
{
    $values = $this->readPostValues();
    $this->performUpsert($values);

    return redirect('/user');
}


private function performUpsert(array $values): void
{
    if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
        DB::table('users')->insert($values);

        return;
    }

    DB::table('users')->where('id', $_POST['id'])->update($values);
}

private function readPostValues(): array
{
    $values = [
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'password' => $_POST['password'],
        'contacto' => $_POST['contact'],
    ];

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $values['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['nif'])) {
        $values['nif'] = $_POST['nif'];
    }

    return $values;
}
```

Comment: No a bad approach, but you could also use Laravel's `updateOrInsert()` method: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#updates. Your method name `performUpsert()` suggests that's what you're doing, but with a bit of extra steps :)

Comment: I haven't used laravel in a few years, had forgotten, thank you :)